# Copy array using Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, algorithm

I'm trying to copy a String array into another String array. However the copy has to contain only parts of each string of the original Array.

For example, If we have

```
 String[] originalArray = {"/data/test2/", "/data/test4/", "/data/dropbox/test5/"}
```

I want the copy array to be

```
 String[] copyArray = {"test2", "test4", "test5"}
```

**My solution would be to simply iterate through the original array and use regular expression to grab the last part of the string in the originalArray and make a copyArray consisting of those values.**

Is the above method valid, or is there a more efficient solution to this? Also what regular expression would I use for this case? The way I'm doing seems a bit too brute forced.

Ideally, I would just manually create the copyArray, but in this case, the size of the originalArray and the precise content is unknown.

**Edit**:

This seems trivial but for some reason it's not working.

I added the regular expression. It seems to work in the tester but it's not working as I wanted it to in the program. I first converted the originalArray into a String with | appended for the regex.

```
String pattern = "/\\w+(?=\\||$)/g";
String testArray = originalArray.replaceAll(pattern," ");
```

However test array is just giving me the original concatenated String without the regex applied.

Comment: Is java 8 in scope for this question?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Is there something in 8 that is useful for this?

Comment: If these are file paths, you can perhaps use `new File(pathname).getName()` to extract the last portion of the path, instead of a regex.  Although it's probably a bit less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to java 7, you need to code a loop, but java 8 introduced streams that allow a fluent one-line solution:

```
String[] names = Arrays.stream(originalArray)
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll(".*/", ""))
    .toArray();
```

The important bit is the [lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to convert the path to the name by using regex to replace everything up to and including the last slash with a blank (effectively removing it).

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine. Note that the length of an array is always known through its `length` field. You should create the copy using `new String[originalArray.length]`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an array of string you could join it using something like `|` and then apply a single RexEx to the whole string like:

```
/\w+(?=\||$)/g
```

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lE5bB3/1)

Comment: If you see my edited post, I tried this on my string and it isn't working as the demo. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use regex for this simple requirement. Simply use `String#lastIndexOf()` to get the index of last `/` and use `String#substring()` method to get the desired sub-string.

Sample code:

```
String[] originalArray = {"/data/test2", "/data/test4", "/data/dropbox/test5"};
String[] copyArray=new String[originalArray.length];

for(int i=0;i<originalArray.length;i++){
    copyArray[i]=originalArray[i].substring(originalArray[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] files(String[] originalArray) {
  List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(originalArray.length);
  for (String s : originalArray) 
    copy.add(originalArray[idx].replaceFirst(".*([^/]*)$", "$1"));
  return copy.toArray(new String[copy.size()]);
}
```